# contextual action bar with gray overlay

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I have a light gray background for the contextual action bar. But on a Nexus 5 I have also a darker overlay and I don't know why :-(

[image: contextual action bar with gray overlay]

I think the images for the background are okay.

[image: cab background mdpi]
[image: cab background hdpi]
[image: cab background xhdpi]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't have resources for `xxhdpi` for Action Mode. Use [Android Action Bar Styles Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), generate resources for your `Action Bar` in the `action mode` and apply it. It will fix your problem.

[image: xxhdpi top]
[image: xxhdpi bottom]